# What's the best way to back up the list of installed apps on your Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, backup, time-machine

As I understand, Time Machine or for that matter, any backup solution doesn't backup your apps (for technical reasons, I know).

**So what's the best solution to remember/backup the list of apps you have installed on your Mac in case it just stops working one day?**

Apart from the obvious "manually write down the name of the app on paper", of course.

Comment: The best list of Applications isn't the one you have, but the ones you use. Get them when you need it. Make a local repository/cache if you need to when you re-download a program.

Comment: How exactly do I go about doing that? There are apps that I use every day and there are apps that I need once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 6):

Time Machine *does* back up your applications. You can restore from a Time Machine backup and your computer will have the system software, applications, and user files it had when it was completely backed up. See [this Apple page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427) for details.

Some other backup solutions (such as Crashplan) generally are set to just back up the /Users folder - Time Machine is a "bare metal" backup.

Comment: What about application preferences? I know that they are restored when doing a full system restoration. However, what if I uninstalled an app along with its preferences using cleaning tools - and now I want to restore just that one app with its last preferences?

Comment: Good question. Post it as a question, and people can answer it @gentmatt

Comment: You're right. Will do so now. :)

Comment: Really? Thanks for pointing it out. I was always under the impression that Time Machine backed up everything except applications.